# lua io.popen() commands with ö, ä, ü, ß

Tags: lua

I'm writing something in lua and I come to a problem.
I know that you can execute cmd commands from lua with io.popen()

I did something like

```
function move(from, to)
  io.popen(string.format([==[move %s %s]==], from, to))
end
```

but I've come to a problem because I'm german and my files sometimes have ö, ä, ü or ß in them and then it breaks.

How can I get it to work with all german characters?

I searched and found a possible solution `io.popen("chcp 1252")` but I can't get it to work.

edit: I'm using Window 7.

Comment: Do you use Windows?

Comment: Your `from` and `to` filenames must be encoded in 1252 codepage.  You must convert them manually from UTF-8 prior to invoking io.popen, io.open, os.execute and other Lua library functions.

Comment: Use `your_filename:fromutf8()` from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41855842/1847592) question.

Comment: try run command in one string `chcp 1252 & echo weiß`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `your_filename:fromutf8()` and no matter what I did it did not work.
I also tried `chcp 1252 & echo weiß` and it didn't change anything but I figured it out in the end.

```
local ersetzen = {
    [142] = string.char(196), --Ä
    [132] = string.char(228), --ä
    [153] = string.char(214), --Ö
    [148] = string.char(246), --ö
    [154] = string.char(220), --Ü
    [129] = string.char(252), --ü
    [225] = string.char(223), --ß
}

local function split(...)
  local output = {}
  for i = 1, string.len(...) do
    output[i] = string.sub(..., i, i)
  end
  return output
end

local function konvertieren(datei)
    local a = split(datei)
    local rest = {}
    for k, v in pairs(a) do
        table.insert(rest, (ersetzen[string.byte(v)] or v))
    end
    return table.concat(rest)
end
```

There might be a shorter way but this works for me.

Comment: So, you are converting from CP850 (MSDOS encoding) to CP1252 (Windows encoding). You are not using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

```
local cp850_to_cp1252 = {
   ['\128'] = '\199',
   ['\129'] = '\252',
   ['\130'] = '\233',
   ['\131'] = '\226',
   ['\132'] = '\228',
   ['\133'] = '\224',
   ['\134'] = '\229',
   ['\135'] = '\231',
   ['\136'] = '\234',
   ['\137'] = '\235',
   ['\138'] = '\232',
   ['\139'] = '\239',
   ['\140'] = '\238',
   ['\141'] = '\236',
   ['\142'] = '\196',
   ['\143'] = '\197',
   ['\144'] = '\201',
   ['\145'] = '\230',
   ['\146'] = '\198',
   ['\147'] = '\244',
   ['\148'] = '\246',
   ['\149'] = '\242',
   ['\150'] = '\251',
   ['\151'] = '\249',
   ['\152'] = '\255',
   ['\153'] = '\214',
   ['\154'] = '\220',
   ['\155'] = '\248',
   ['\156'] = '\163',
   ['\157'] = '\216',
   ['\158'] = '\215',
   ['\159'] = '\131',
   ['\160'] = '\225',
   ['\161'] = '\237',
   ['\162'] = '\243',
   ['\163'] = '\250',
   ['\164'] = '\241',
   ['\165'] = '\209',
   ['\166'] = '\170',
   ['\167'] = '\186',
   ['\168'] = '\191',
   ['\169'] = '\174',
   ['\170'] = '\172',
   ['\171'] = '\189',
   ['\172'] = '\188',
   ['\173'] = '\161',
   ['\174'] = '\171',
   ['\175'] = '\187',
   ['\176'] = '?',
   ['\177'] = '?',
   ['\178'] = '?',
   ['\179'] = '?',
   ['\180'] = '?',
   ['\181'] = '\193',
   ['\182'] = '\194',
   ['\183'] = '\192',
   ['\184'] = '\169',
   ['\185'] = '?',
   ['\186'] = '?',
   ['\187'] = '?',
   ['\188'] = '?',
   ['\189'] = '\162',
   ['\190'] = '\165',
   ['\191'] = '?',
   ['\192'] = '?',
   ['\193'] = '?',
   ['\194'] = '?',
   ['\195'] = '?',
   ['\196'] = '?',
   ['\197'] = '?',
   ['\198'] = '\227',
   ['\199'] = '\195',
   ['\200'] = '?',
   ['\201'] = '?',
   ['\202'] = '?',
   ['\203'] = '?',
   ['\204'] = '?',
   ['\205'] = '?',
   ['\206'] = '?',
   ['\207'] = '\164',
   ['\208'] = '\240',
   ['\209'] = '\208',
   ['\210'] = '\202',
   ['\211'] = '\203',
   ['\212'] = '\200',
   ['\213'] = '?',
   ['\214'] = '\205',
   ['\215'] = '\206',
   ['\216'] = '\207',
   ['\217'] = '?',
   ['\218'] = '?',
   ['\219'] = '?',
   ['\220'] = '?',
   ['\221'] = '\166',
   ['\222'] = '\204',
   ['\223'] = '?',
   ['\224'] = '\211',
   ['\225'] = '\223',
   ['\226'] = '\212',
   ['\227'] = '\210',
   ['\228'] = '\245',
   ['\229'] = '\213',
   ['\230'] = '\181',
   ['\231'] = '\254',
   ['\232'] = '\222',
   ['\233'] = '\218',
   ['\234'] = '\219',
   ['\235'] = '\217',
   ['\236'] = '\253',
   ['\237'] = '\221',
   ['\238'] = '\175',
   ['\239'] = '\180',
   ['\240'] = '\173',
   ['\241'] = '\177',
   ['\242'] = '?',
   ['\243'] = '\190',
   ['\244'] = '\182',
   ['\245'] = '\167',
   ['\246'] = '\247',
   ['\247'] = '\184',
   ['\248'] = '\176',
   ['\249'] = '\168',
   ['\250'] = '\183',
   ['\251'] = '\185',
   ['\252'] = '\179',
   ['\253'] = '\178',
   ['\254'] = '?',
   ['\255'] = '\160',
}

function string.from850(filename)
   return (filename:gsub(".", cp850_to_cp1252))
end
```

Usage:  `your_filename:from850()`