# Problem with accents while copying files in LUA

Tags: windows, lua, character-encoding

I have an issue with the accents with French Windows 10

```
local origin = "D:\temp\test.txt"
local destination = "D:\temp\testé.txt"
local cpTemplate = "copy \""..origin.."\" \""..destination.."\""
os.execute(cpTemplate)
```

A console log correctly shows:

`copy "D:\temp\test.txt" "D:\temp\testé.txt"`

This does not create a "testé.txt" file but:

`testÃ©.txt`

Of course, if there is an accent in the folder name (D:\temp here is an example), nothing is copied

Comment: and just using teste.txt is not an option? In my opinion file names should not contain any character decorations at all.

Comment: This is an example. In the real life I can't ask the users to avoid using accents, which are quite common in french language :)

Comment: maybe this solves your problem https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/2458547aa3b9210a8b5f686ac08ecbf0

Comment: your file is saved in UTF8 encoding, `os.executes` uses ansi version and uses `windows-1252` encoding. In your situation it is not perfect but should work only converting `utf8` to `windows1252` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41859181/12918181 or simply save your script in `windows1252` encoding.

Comment: Solved with [stackoverflow.com/a/41859181/12918181](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41859181/12918181) thanks to Darius

Comment: BTW, this is the [latest version](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2033412) of the ANSI-UTF8 converter supporting several codepages.  You need `utf8_to_win()` from there.

Comment: The link in my previous comment became broken, so I reuploaded ANSI-UTF8 converter [here](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/44a88f64f9a497919db4ad8c28259a8f)

Answer (score 1):

Standard Lua runtime library (the "io" module) does not support writing UTF8 or UNICODE filenames to disk, as Lua relies on the ANSI C runtime library. You have to manually convert the filename to the current console codepage used on your Windows system (as Darius suggested)

You can also use a specific Lua implementation for Windows that uses UTF8 strings and can write UTF8 filenames to disk such as LuaRT (https://www.luart.org)