# LUA : How to print a Latin1 string with io.write()?

Tags: windows, lua

In Lua 5.4, I tried to print sone strings in Latin1 encoding with io.write(), but some characters (à,é...) are not well printed,

How could I perform this ?

Here is a screenshot of failed print with win-125x.lua

[image: [1]: should be €€€]

Comment: This depends on the encoding used in the terminal. Lua is agnostic with respect to encodings in strings.

Comment: `io.write(win_to_utf8(your_string))`, use [this](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2033412) module, set `codepage = 1252` for Latin1

Comment: I tried but it does not work :/

Comment: Please post a screenshot of "not well printed" output for `€€€` input.

Comment: it prints ??? instead of €€€

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are running Lua on Windows.
Because you are converting Latin1 characters to UTF8, you should set the Windows console codepage to UTF8 before running your Lua script, with the following command :

```
chcp 65001
```

An other option is to save your script with UTF8 encoding without the need to convert strings from cp1252 to UTF8 and use the chcp command before running your script.

Remember that standard Lua has no concept of string encoding and that Windows support for UTF8 characters in the console is incomplete. Hence this kind of problems.

Check that related question too : [Problem with accents while copying files in LUA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849835/problem-with-accents-while-copying-files-in-lua)

Comment: Or `chcp 1252` for usual non-UTF8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

If you have the table `utf8` you can do...

```
> do io.write(utf8.char(8364):rep(3)..'\n'):flush() end
€€€
```

To get the code you can do...

```
> do io.write(utf8.codepoint('€')..'\n'):flush() end
8364
```

But i am not sure if that works on windows.
...i am on linux.

Comment: It doesn't work because of wrong codepage on windows